# How to call a function for each element with a particular class, every time the window scrolls (jquery))

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a scroll-triggered function which slides elements in from one side based on the scroll position. I would like it to run on all elements with 'my-class', but currently my code seems to think 'this' is the window, not each 'my-class' element. Is there something wrong with the way I am calling the function? How can I get each element to run the function?

Here is the basic html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <div class="not-my-class"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <div class="not-my-class"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
</div>
```

some CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.my-class, .not-my-class {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #888888;
}
```

And the jquery:

```
function fadeIn($element) {
$scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$windowHeight = $(window).height();
$pageHeight = $('body').height();
$elementHeight = $($element).height();
$baseOffset = $($element).offset().top;
$length = 100;
$finalOffset = $baseOffset + ( $elementHeight / 2 );
$current = ( $scrollTop - ( $finalOffset - ($windowHeight / 2 ) - ( $length / 2 ) ) ) / $length;
if ($current > 1) {
    $current = 1;
}
else {
    if ($current < 0) {
        $current = 0;
    }
    else {}
}
$opacity = $current;
$slide = ( $current * 100 ) - 100;
$(this).css({"opacity": $opacity, "left": $slide, "position": "relative"});
}
$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
    $('.my-class').each(fadeIn(this));
});
```

Comment: Maybe a callback on each? : $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
    $('.my-class').each(function(){FadeIn(this) } );
});

Comment: Great examples in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/). The basic problem is [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) in your code is from the outer anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks guys, that has fixed it. @user3791775 if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. working a treat now.
Edit: There has just been two more correct answers. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a function like so:

```
$('.my-class').each(function(){ 
  fadeIn(this) 
});
```

So that `this` is referring to the .my-class element instead of the window

Comment: This answer worked. Here is the correct code for reference.

`$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
 $('.my-class').each(function(){
  fadeIn(this);
 });
});`

Answer (score 1):

At first glance you should change the each call to

```
$('.my-class').each(function(){ fadeIn(this) });
```

so it runs at the right moment and gains the correct scope.